# Hello, which one is correct grammatically?

Tags: adverbs, infinitives, relative-clauses, clauses

1. Please share your offers with me to evaluate.
2. Please share your offers to evaluate with me.
3. Please share with me to evaluate your offers.

Comment: Firstly, must I point out that "gramatically" is spelt with a *double* m; i.e. "grammatically" ;)

Comment: Thank you for correcting. what about my question? :)

Comment: ...I am thinking... I think I know the answer, but to answer your question on this site, I need to provide some evidence and not just some mere intuition. (+1) :P

Comment: You're trying to "fuse" two different constructions - *share X **with me*** and *[in order] **for me** to evaluate [X]*. This can't really work with a single instance of the word ***me***, no matter how you arrange the other elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.                                                                                    
"Please share your offers with me for me to evaluate them." Is this the correct sentence? As far as I understand, the other forms are unclear and incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two are grammatically ok but could be interpreted slightly differently.

> Please share your offers with me to evaluate.

This suggests that you share the offers you've had with me and then I will evaluate them.

> Please share your offers to evaluate with me.

This suggests that you share the offers you've had with me and then we will evaluate them together.

The last is a clumsy construction which leaves it unclear what should be shared with me.